# ImageView content loading from to another ImageView

Tags: android, imageview, urlloader

If it possible to write ImageView to another ImageView?

For example:

```
        ImageView image1= (ImageView)findByVie(R.id.image1)
        ImageView image2= (ImageView)findByVie(R.id.image2)

        Glide.with(context).load(url).into(image1);

    image2=image1 
// I want to write image from image 1 
//to image 2 without loading it again from internet.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
ImageView image1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image1);
ImageView image2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image2);

Glide.with(context).load(url).into(image1);
image2.setImageDrawable(image1.getDrawable();
```

However, with the way Glide works, it caches images it has loaded so calling `Glide.with(context).load(url).into(image2);` again would just load the image from the cache, not from the remote server again.

EDIT:

If you call `getDrawable` straight after calling Glide then it won't work, because Glide is still fetching the image so the first imageview is still empty. You need to use glides callback in order to make sure the image has been loaded before calling `getDrawable`

```
Glide.with(context).load(url).listener(new RequestListener).into(image1);
```

Comment: image2.setImageDrawable(image1.getDrawable(); i tried that way and the image was empty. Okay i thought about the cache mechanism and i wasnt sure how glide handle with it

Comment: you need to call it after the image has loaded, at the minute Glide is being told to get the image and the second imageview is being populated before the image has loaded, if you call Glide.with(context).load(url).listener(new RequestListener).into(image1) then add the getDrawable code in the callback then it should work

Answer (score 0):

```
Bitmap bm=((BitmapDrawable)imageView1.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
imgview2.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

Answer (score 0):

As your are using **Glide** to load image from url. Glide will use its cache to load image for second imageview it won't use internet to load same image in second imageview.

You can also use the following way to load image once for sure

```
  Glide.with(this).load("url").into(new SimpleTarget<GlideDrawable>() {
                @Override
                public void onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, GlideAnimation<? super GlideDrawable> glideAnimation) {

                    image1.setImageDrawable(resource);
 image2.setImageDrawable(resource);


                }
            });
```